# Configure smtp for Symfony at platform.sh

Tags: symfony, email, deployment, swiftmailer

Platform.sh doesn't allow to edit neither parameters.yml nor any other file through SSH. How can I configure SMTP in order to send mails using Symfony application's SwiftMailer? [This](https://docs.platform.sh/administration/web/email.html) documentations says

> In Symfony, if you use the default SwiftMailer service, we recommend the following settings in your app/config/parameters.yaml:

```
parameters:
     mailer_transport: sendmail
     mailer_host: null
     mailer_user: null
     mailer_password: null
```

But I work with existing application which was wrongly configured, I think. This is what I have in parameters.yml file now:

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: symfony
    database_user: root
    database_password: null
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: null
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out this issue with editing parameters.dist.yml file with the values I wanted to use. Platform.sh deployment systems doesn't asks me about the values to input inside parameters.yml file (which should be gitignored, as you may know), so write the values you want to have as a result, right in the parameters.dist.yml. That will not affect local version but will allow to change the content of the parameters.yml file.

Answer (score 0):

In your parameters.yml set the following:

```
parameters:
    ...
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 192.168.3.100
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
```

Where `mailer_host` is the IP address (The above is an example IP Address) of your SMTP server. I use this all the time.

Comment: I can't edit this file because platform.sh allows to integrate with SSH only in read-only environment.

Comment: Yes, you can also edit the `parameters.yml.dist` file. When you do a `composer update` it will use the `parameters.yml.dist` to create a `parameters.yml` file. My answer is still correct, because you need to set those values, whether it is the `yml` or the `dist` file.